# .htaccess rules blocking legitimate traffic

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Problem: legitimate traffic to my site is receiving "403 Forbidden" errors.

Example: A request from `199.16.156.125` to `GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1` from user-agent `Twitterbot/1.0` should be allowed, but is denied.

Suspected culprit: my root .htaccess file implements the 5G Firewall from PerishablePress; additional deny rules from various WordPress security plugins; a couple of deny rules that I have hacked together myself; and a long list of banned CIDRs.

Sample code (truncated):

```
# ban all requests via HTTP/1.0
# UNLESS they are requests to either wp-cron or admin-ajax.
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(HTTP/1\.1)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php.*|/wp-cron\.php.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</ifModule>

# 5G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (casper|cmsworldmap|diavol|dotbot)   keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (flicky|ia_archiver|kmccrew) keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (libwww|planetwork|pycurl|skygrid)   keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent  (SISTRIX|AhrefsBot|YandexBot|Baidu|SiteExplorer|MJ12bot|Browserlet|msnbot\-media) keep_out
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (Java|Wget|CPython|ruby|panscient\.com) keep_out
 <Limit GET POST PUT>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from env=keep_out
 </Limit>
</IfModule>

#allowed IP (example)
allow from 255.255.255.255

#banned networks
deny from 199.119.224.0/22
deny from 199.30.48.0/21
deny from 99.198.96.0/19
```

There's more to it than that, but I suspect the problem may be in the above sample code.

What have I tried: 1. edit .htaccess rules to attempt to resolve issue. 2. create 403 logger script to provide additional details about requests that receive a 403 response.  (The hypothesis was that the forbidden requests might include additional X-Forwarded-For headers that contain IP addresses from banned networks; however, it turned out that this hypothesis was not correct.) 3. bang head against desk.

**EDIT**

If the general consensus is that the posted snippet could not be causing the problem I'm describing, I will accept an answer that helps me to track down the actual cause of the problem through more effective troubleshooting.

**UPDATE**

I appreciate the community's input and thought I would provide an update.

Eventually,  I contacted my web host for help. After a little back-and-forth, I learned that my host had indeed banned Twitterbot from their network for being a resource hog, apparently by visiting sites running poorly optimized WordPress plugins.  So that specific result was not, in fact, an .htaccess issue after all.

However, I still have a client who can't access my site, gets 403 forbidden message instead: legitimate traffic is getting denied, as described above.  My host confirmed they are *not* blocking my client's IP address.  I still haven't found a resolution for this.  I have even listed his dedicated IP in an "allow" directive before my list of "deny" directives, and still he's denied.  I edited the code example above to demonstrate.

Comment: Are you sure you're not banning them in the banned networks at the bottom? You didn't show them all. You truncated it.

Comment: The list of banned networks is arranged sequentially, starting with (theoretically) 1.0.0.0/8 and continuing to 99.0.0.0/8 so it should be easy to identify visually whether a given IP is within a banned network. So I don't think that's the issue.  It's a valid question though. I can post the entire list of banned networks if you think that would help.

Comment: The reason I asked is because you have some 199.x.x.x subnets and you might be including in one of those. What are your 199.x.x.x banned networks?

Comment: Just the ones I listed. That section goes: deny from 198.143.128.0/18
deny from 198.147.20.0/22
deny from 198.23.128.0/17
deny from 198.23.150.128/26
deny from 198.27.64.0/18
deny from 198.50.128.0/17
deny from 199.119.224.0/22
deny from 199.30.48.0/21
deny from 2.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 1):

I realise this was posted a while ago and most likely resolved

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php.*|/wp-cron\.php.*)
```

is going to forbidden if not /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php or /wp-cron.php
therefore /robots.txt will fail as it falls within the catchment of NOT represented by the !